# Tesseract OCR iOS with MICR data return Exception on configEngine

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

I'm trying to get MICR numbers from an image using Tesseract OCR. I have mcr.traineddata which I get from below link. I put it inside tessdata folder and delete everything about eng and other languages.

https://github.com/BigPino67/Tesseract-MICR-OCR

I'm declaring Tesseract and process image with below code

```
if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "mcr") {
 tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
 tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .auto
 tesseract.image = image.g8_blackAndWhite()
 tesseract.recognize()
 textView.text = tesseract.recognizedText
}
```

However, It gives

> other_case < unicharset_size:Error:Assert failed:in file unicharset.cpp, line 869

error from `G8Tesseract.mm` file inside `TesseractOCRiOS` framework. Below is the function and It gives error on `int returnCode = _......` line. I guess It is something about being UTF8String because I'm trying to OCR MICR. However, I don't know how to solve it.

```
- (BOOL)configEngine
{
    GenericVector<STRING> tessKeys;
    for( NSString *key in self.configDictionary.allKeys ){
        tessKeys.push_back(STRING(key.UTF8String));
    }

    GenericVector<STRING> tessValues;
    for( NSString *val in self.configDictionary.allValues ){
        tessValues.push_back(STRING(val.UTF8String));
    }

    int count = (int)self.configFileNames.count;
    const char **configs = count ? (const char **)malloc(sizeof(const char *) * count) : NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        configs[i] = ((NSString*)self.configFileNames[i]).UTF8String;
    }
    int returnCode = _tesseract->Init(self.absoluteDataPath.UTF8String, self.language.UTF8String,
                                      (tesseract::OcrEngineMode)self.engineMode,
                                      (char **)configs, count,
                                      &tessKeys, &tessValues,
                                      false);
    if (configs != nullptr) {
        free(configs);
    }
    return returnCode == 0;
}
```

Example of what I try to OCR:

[image]

Comment: Looks like tessdata file you are using was trained for the different version of tesseract. I can't find any mentions of the version in the link you provided, so you will have to train it again for the fresh tesseract.

Comment: How can I train a new one?

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract

Comment: I added what I want to ocr.